# replacement of taskForCompletionOfAllTasks in android?

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, bolts-framework

I am fetching some objects from a class which are used to some other objects from other classes. I have implement it in iOS with `taskForCompletionOfAllTasks`. How can I implement same in Android. Is there any method which works same on Android which is used `taskForCompletionOfAllTasks` works on iOS?

Comment: instead of referring ios component just specify what do you wanna achieve in android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `Task.whenAll()`
https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android#tasks-in-parallel